# How to echo a formatted date in PHP from an array

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, cakephp

I have a datetime column in MySQL let's call it `$time`.  It's coming form a CakePHP form.  If I try to echo it I get I just get "Array".  If I `print_r()` on it I get:

```
Array ( [month] => 10 [day] => 30 [year] => 2010 [hour] => 16 [min] => 30 )
```

I want to echo this out as a formatted date, nothing seems to work because it's not a string but an array.  Do I have to go like this:

```
echo $time['month'].'-'.$time['day'].'-'.$time['year'].' '.$time['hour'].':'.$time['min'];
```

or can I use the `date` function?

Comment: I presume that you are trying to do this outside of CakePHP?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One simple, procedural way is to use [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) in conjunction with [`mktime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php), like so. `date()` formats based on a UNIX timestamp; `mktime()` provides a timestamp based on your array values:

```
$timestamp = mktime($time['hour'], $time['min'], 0, $time['month'], $time['day'], $time['year']);
echo date('M-d-Y H:i', $timestamp);
```

For a more object-oriented approach with the `DateTime` class, refer to [Gordon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4046870/how-to-echo-a-formatted-date-in-php-from-an-array/4046999#4046999).

Comment: thanks for your help!  Thanks to everyone else too, this one worked right away though.

Answer (score 5):

You can do:

```
$dt = new DateTime;
$dt->setDate($time['year'], $time['month'], $time['day']);
$dt->setTime($time['hour'], $time['minute']);
echo $dt->format(DateTime::ISO8601);
```

You can put any format into `format()` that is also supported with `date()`.
You do not need PHP5.3 for this.

Use the above if you need to create a date that is not already contained in the array. If you simply want a 'Y-m-d H:i' format, you can use

```
printf("%d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d",
       $time['year'], $time['month'], $time['day'],
       $time['hour'], $time['min']);
```

or with argument swapping and passing the entire array (though you have to rely on the order then):

```
vprintf('%3$d-%1$02d-%2$02d %4$02d:%5$02d', $time);
```

Needless to say, you can also use [`vsprintf`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.vsprintf.php) or `sprintf` to create a datetime string that can be parsed with `DateTime` or `strtotime`, e.g.

```
$dt = new DateTime(vsprintf('%3$d-%1$02d-%2$02d %4$02d:%5$02d', $time));
```

which you could then format as shown in the first example.

Comment: I thought of `vprintf()` too, but as you say, ordering of elements then becomes a concern.

Answer (score 2):

> Do I have to go like this:

That is one option, yes.

> or can I use the date function?

Not with the data in the current form.

You could consider converting the array into a proper timestamp or `DateTime` object for maximum flexibility in formatting, calculations etc.

- For a timestamp, see [`mktime()`](http://www.php.net/mktime) (You'll have to feed it the members of your array. **Update**: @BoltClock has an example.)
- For a `DateTime` object - it's PHP5's new, object-oriented, [Year 2038 bug-free](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem), and much better way of dealing with dates - see [`CreateFromFormat()`](http://php.net/manual/en//datetime.createfromformat.php) (Needs PHP 5.3+, though)

Answer (score 1):

The date() function has an optional argument $timestamp. You can `echo date("MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm, $time)` and avoid manual formatting.

I hope the $time value is declared as `TIMESTAMP` in MySQL for this to work

Answer (score 1):

Date function wants a timestamp. But you could use a custom function, such as:

```
function fd($time) {
   return "$time[month]-$time[day]-$time[year] $time[hour]:$time[minute]";
}

// Sample usage
echo fd($time);
```

Answer (score 0):

Does the Time helper not suit the needs here? Just pass the whole array to it and use the functions it provides.